# list tkinter combobox options with suboptions

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, combobox, tkinter

Not sure if I've seen this done before with a combobox without building a custom one. I'm building my own ebay spider and I want the user to be able to select from a list of categories to crawl over for their queries etc. Each category has it's own subcategories of course. And you can't explicitly select a subcategory of a category in ebay's advanced search form. However, you can send the subcategory id with the form submission request to automatically search within that subcategory.

After crawling over the categories on ebays site getting all categories -> subcategories for that category I essentially have a dictionary that looks something along the lines of this:

```
categories = {main_category_title: [sub_category1, ...., sub_categoryn],
              ....}
```

I know how to get all subcategories listed by themselves into the combobox by doing something like this:

```
self.categories = ttk.Combobox(self,
              values = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
              (ebay_spider.categories[category] for category in ebay_spider.categories))))
```

While this works... it's not really what I want since it doesn't allow the user to select the main category containing each subcategory and it looks rather convoluted.

Is there a way to list the main categories with the subcategories below them? Preferrably indented.

**Approach 1:**
An alternative I thought of was to make a textbox with a button inside for each category / subcategory that sets a tk.StringVar containing the value since I can handle indentation this way, but would prefer to not have to do that if there's a simpler approach.

**Approach 2:**
When getting all sub categories I could just do something like 
"  " (some arbitrary amount of whitespace) + subcategory while putting them into the list.

This is "hackish" imo and when using this later grabbing the subcategories I'd have to call .strip(). This works at the caveat of having to use .strip() when using the subcategories elsewhere

Comment: What about 2 `Combobox` side by side, have the secondary category combo update its values accordingly whenever the user changes the main category combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example of using 2 combo boxes.  The main category uses a `StringVar()` with a trace so that when it is changed it updates the values of the second category.  If the user enters something that is not found in the dict of categories then a blank value of `'--None--'` is set instead:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

def main_change(*args):
    second.set('--None--')
    second['values'] = categories.get(main_selected.get(), ['--None--'])

categories = {'Fruit': ['Apples', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'], 'Vegetables': ['Peas', 'Carrots']}

root = Tk()

main_selected = StringVar()
main_selected.trace('w', main_change)

main = ttk.Combobox(root, values=list(categories.keys()), textvariable=main_selected)
main.pack()
second = ttk.Combobox(root, values=['--None--'])
second.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There are a couple of other ways of achieving this, so depending on your application you may want to look into them, one would be using the `postcommand()` method of `Combobox()`.

Comment: list(categories.keys()) for python 3